# Mouse pick point snap to isnappingfeedback location

Tags: arcobjects

I have created one BaseTool for placing point on polygon feature. mousemove event showing mouse move time vertex & edges & endPoints but picked point snapped at vertex.

```
 public override void OnMouseMove(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
        {
            IMxDocument pMxdoc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap pMap = pMxdoc.FocusMap;                      
            pPosition = pMxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
            if (pPosition != null)
            {

                ISnappingResult snapResult = null;                
                //Try to snap the current position
                snapResult = pSnapper.Snap(pPosition);
                pSnappingFeedback.Update(snapResult, 0);
                ISnapAgent agent = pSnappingEnv as ISnapAgent;                
                if (snapResult != null)
                {
                    pPosition = snapResult.Location;   
                }
                else
                {
                    IPoint point = pMxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
                    var activeView = pMxdoc.ActiveView;
                    point = pPosition;
                    var Chamged = psnapEnv.SnapPoint(point);
                }
            }
            // TODO:  Add Tool1.OnMouseMove implementation
        }  

 public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
        {            
            IMxDocument pMxdoc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap pMap = pMxdoc.FocusMap;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView pview = pMxdoc.FocusMap as IActiveView;
            pMap.ClearSelection();             
            pPosition = pMxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y);
            if (pPosition != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pMap.LayerCount; i++)
                {
                    ILayer pLayer = pMap.Layer[i];
                    IFeatureLayer pFlayer = pLayer as IFeatureLayer;
                    IFeatureClass pFclass = pFlayer.FeatureClass;
                    if (pLayer.Name == "Edit Comment")
                    {
                        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point pntclass = pMxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y)as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point;                       
                        CreateFeature(pFclass, pPosition, pFlayer);                        
                    }
                }
            }
            // TODO:  Add Tool1.OnMouseDown implementation
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You're not snapping in your OnMouseDown. You're using OnMoueMove to handle all your snapping bits, well sort of, what's pSnapper initialized to? Why not then make the snapped location global and not use the X and Y from the mouse down to locate your pPosition.